# What does this code mean?

Tags: programming

Here solutions is array .
I need to know why this code is written.Please help me.

```
solutionsMod = Mod[solutions, n];

For[j = 1, j <= Length@solutions, j++,
   For[i = 1, j <= Length@solution[[1]], i++,
       If[solutionsMod[[j, i]] == 0, solutionsMod[[i, i]] =n;
           ];];];

Export[Tostring[n] <> ".txt", solutionsMod, "CSV"];
```

[original png image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzZTn.png)

Comment: Please, in the future, post copyable code, not images.

Comment: This is a math question and not relevant to the underlying software being used.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtbau The need to use `Mod[i,n,1]` instead of `Mod[i,n]` is very common when indices have to go from 1..,n instead of 0..n-1, such as for list, vector, or array indices in Mathematica.

Comment: @Somos I realize that (it's something I sometimes need myself). It's still basically a question about math-- such need can arise in any programming language.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You have a point, but, still, it arises in the context of Mathematica and very few languages have the equivalent of `Mod[i,n,k]`. It would me more complicated to have to explain the question in MSE.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the `For`-loop looks like a very obfuscated and inefficient way of computing

```
solutionMods = Mod[solutions, n, 1];
```

Comment: Why need to Mod[] in cases of array?

Comment: @Thuriya, that question is a bit unclear; did you not take the `Mod[]` of the `solutions` array yourself in your question?

Comment: @ThuriyaThwin "Why need to Mod[] in cases of array? " The someone who created the code wanted each value in the array(?) `solutions` modded by `n` but with result `n` in case of `0`. As I neither know who wrote that nor the purpose, how should I tell? Really, your questions lack a lot of context. Please provide all relevant information (in the future).

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Henrik Schumacher is brief and to the point. However, the user may actually want to use a modified version instead.

```
solutions = Mod[solutions, n] + 1;
```

The reason why is that in order to map `0..n-1` to `1..n` in a contiguous way you need `i -> i+1`. The use of `Mod[i, n, 1]` only changes the mapping of `0` to `n` which is exactly what you want in order to fix an original mapping using `Mod[i, n]`. Thus, perhaps the best solution may be to fix the original code to use something like `Mod[i, n] + 1` instead of `Mod[i, n]`.